# Converting sql number to date

Tags: mysql

I have a table for an events system that contains what I believe to be the start and end date of the event in number format.

I have tried multiple methods to convert the number but none work.

For example, I have the column 'event_start_ts' and the number

```
1488621600
```

and that should equal the date

```
04-03-2017
```

How do I convert this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes my apologies, this worked for me.

Comment: select from_unixtime(1488621600)